# Limiting Result with Subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to RxJS. I am using it in one of my Angular applications. I would like to achieve the following. For the given set of user_ids :ex [1, 2, 3], (i) pull the user details from the database , once I get the user details, then I would like to pull the user_reservation details from other database table (ii) subscribe and release the subscription in ngOnDestroy() method.

Here is what i tried...

```js
let user_ids= [1,2,3];

user_ids.forEach
((id) =>
{
    this.subscription = this.http.get(`https://someUrl/api/userdetails/${id}`)
        .pipe(
            map((x:any) => x.id),

            concatMap(userid => 
                this.http.get(`https://someUrl/api/reservationDetails? 
                         userId=${userid}`)),

             take(2)
         ).subscribe();
})


    ngOnDestroy(): void {
          if(this.subscription) { 
              this.subscription.unsubscribe();
              this.subscription = null;
          }
    }
```

It gives me the result, but when I want to limit the reservation details (I want to take only first two reservation details), (i) it is not working instead it returns all the reservation details of the given user id. (ii) I am declaring the subscription (this.subscription) inside forEach() loop. Will it make any side effects? , because the same subscription is being initialised repeatedly. Any guidance is appreciated.

Edit:
As JGFMK , asked me to provide more information on database operation. I am updating my post. I am using an SQL Server as a backend. But i am not limiting the row from server side query. I just would like to pick up two random (rows) results, i thought RxJS take(2) will limit the results by taking only two rows. (Request you to correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Your server side should be doing something like top 2. You should tag question with database type your are using too.

Comment: What kind of object does ``this.http.get(`https://someUrl/api/reservationDetails?userId=${userid}`)`` return? You'll have to extract the data you want from the returned object you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`take(2)` doesn't work the way you want it. If your observable emits stream of values, it will take only first 2 values and unsubscribe from stream.

To get first 2 rows of userdetails you must implement it in your API to limit the results and pass it in url query, e.g. `https://someUrl/api/reservationDetails?userId=${userid}&limit=2` and then your API will query from the database again using `LIMIT`.

**Update:** As for your subscription, you actually unsubscribe only from the last subscription and you have memory leak here. The better way to handle it would be:

```js
let user_ids= [1,2,3];
this.subscriptions = new Subscription();

user_ids.forEach
((id) =>
{
    this.subscriptions.add(this.http.get(`https://someUrl/api/userdetails/${id}`)
        .pipe(
            map((x:any) => x.id),

            concatMap(userid => 
                this.http.get(`https://someUrl/api/reservationDetails? 
                         userId=${userid}`)),

             take(2)
         ).subscribe());
})


    ngOnDestroy(): void {
          this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: Got it. If it is infinite stream then RxJS will discard take() - operations.Thanks for your response. My second query is can i use 'Subscription' inside forEach()? because it is getting called multiple time? will it lead to any memory leak or other potential issue?

Comment: @RxJS_Learner I've updated my answer for your second part of the question. If your questions are answered please consider accepting and answer.

Comment: of course,i ought to accept it. I am new to Stackoverflow,so i don't know the process.I will accept it now. :)

Comment: @RxJS_Learner Yep, Welcome to StackOverflow community.